# Why is there two AdView banners?

Tags: android, admob

As described in the section of my layout code below, my layout should position my AdView banner at the top left of the screen, which it does. 
But in some cases, it also displays an additional banner (the "bad banner"), of the same size, with a different content, towards the center of the screen. 
See the atatched screenshot of my full tablet screen (1280x800).

I have only one instance of AdView in my code.

I don't know if it's related, but it seems to happen when my app is launched through intent-filter (ACTION_VIEW) from another app, but not when launched normally.

Any idea where this second (annoying) banner could come from?

See screenshot there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYnlm.jpg

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a150a91e636e7f9"
            ads:color_bg="ffffffff"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            android:gravity="top" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/header_icon_logo"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems be correct, try to clean your project and run again. 
the other solution is that once remove your imageview from xml and then check the output.

Comment: You helped me find my mistake: I had inadvertently left a  "layout.addView(adView)" in my code... That's what displayed the 2nd adView. Thanks Mudassar.